# Javascript looping through object, use reference instead of repeating path

Tags: javascript

```
for (var OBJ in a[b][c][d].E) {

    alert(a[b][c][d].E[OBJ].data);

}
```

Instead of doing this is there are way to be more concise by using a reference to an object like below?

```
for (var OBJ in a[b][c][d].E) {

    alert(OBJ.data);

}
```

Comment: You could use a `for-of` loop or use `.forEach`.

Comment: Pointless down vote, useful answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say it yourself, just create a reference...

```
var container = a[b][c][d].E;
for (var OBJ in container) {
    alert(container[OBJ].data);
}
```

OR

```
var container = a[b][c][d].E,
    lookup = function lookup( obj ) {
        return container[obj].data;
    };
for (var OBJ in container) {
    alert(lookup(OBJ));
}
```